# Splitting a string using a regex in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, split

Why do these not behave identically?

```
perl -e '$x = "12aba34ba5"; $, = ", "; print split /[ab]/, $x;'
12, , , 34, , 5

perl -e '$x = "12aba34ba5"; $, = ", "; print split /(a|b)/, $x;'
12, a, , b, , a, 34, b, , a, 5
```

Comment: You're grouping in the second split. If you'd grouped `/[ab]/` to be `/([ab])/` you'd get both the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented in [perldoc split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

> If the PATTERN contains parentheses,
>   additional list elements are created
>   from each matching substring in the
>   delimiter.

You can use `(?:a|b)` if you don't want to make backreferences.